# Javadoc generation error

Tags: java, api, javadoc

I'm trying to generate the Javadoc for my project, but I keep getting a 'no source files for package pack' error.

My files are stored in the directory:

```
/home/epaige/tomcat/webapps/facebook/WEB-INF/classes/pack
```

The package line in all my files reads:

```
package pack;
```

the line i'm using to generate the Javadoc is:

```
javadoc -d /home/epaige/public_html/facebook
```

Can someone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Set your sourcepath with:

```
-sourcepath sourcepathlist
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/javadoc/